# Issue to display Permalink (ACF Relationships in Custom Post Type )

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I use the following code to display links to the first post type(location) in the second post type(doctor page)
But this code will output the link to the page we are on(doctor page). And the location pages link is not displayed. What's the problem?
[ACF Plugin Guides](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/)

```
<?php $locations = get_field('location');?>
      <?php if( $locations ): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach( $locations as $location ): ?>
          <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $location->ID ); ?>">
                <?php echo get_the_title( $location->ID ); ?>
            </a>
          </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Is `get_the_title()` working correctly?

Comment: No. get_the_title() will output the title to the page we are on (The title of this page repeats the number of fields)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `$location` is indeed returning an instance of WP_Post? Or is it returning a direct page id? In case of the second it would be enough to use just `$location` for your functions (get permalink / get title). 

It would be nice if you could link a pastebin link to the return of the following; `var_dump($locatinos)`

Comment: thanks @jim . I am not sure and i do according to ACF guidance. Can you overwrite the code for me To display the links correctly ?

Comment: Can you please provide a dump first? You can do it by running this line of code: `<?php $locations = get_field('location'); var_dump($locations); exit; ?>`

Comment: @jim I tried this too, but it didn't work properly. But the link address was output along with other expressions (array(7) { [0]=> string(50) ")

Comment: It should always be working properly. Could you please deliver the dump so I can look into this?